# Serialise/Deserialise List<String>

Tags: java, android

I was to save an arraylist of strings into 1 column in the local database. I am having some problems doing this. Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong...

```
private String serializeArray(List<String> array) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bytesOut);
        oos.writeObject(array);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytesOut.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private ArrayList<String> deserializeArray(String string) {
    Log.d("USERDAO", string);
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream bytesIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(string, Base64.NO_WRAP));
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bytesIn);
        return (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception when returning the Arraylist on deserialise array. The serialiseArray method does return a string however I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Maybe you can tell where the null pointer exception occurs ? :)

Comment: aren't you getting any Exception Before NullPointer Exception

Comment: Also, don't you notice the asymmetry of the methods? One serializes a `List<String>` (any kind of List), and the other one expects an `ArrayList<String>`. Use List in both methods, or use ArrayList in both methods. But using List in one and ArrayList in the other is wrong.

Comment: The exception occurs in UserTag.java, at line 156, in the method setDropboxFolders. It doesn't occur in any of the methods shown.

Comment: Ah ok, true so the actual error isn't a null pointer exception. It is catching the exception and returning null.

Comment: @Waqas: Not all implementations are serializable. Just try with a `subList()` of an `ArrayList`, for example.

Comment: @jiduvah: yes, this is a bad idea. You should just propaget the exception, or wrap it into a runtime exception and throw this runtime exception. If you want to understand what's wrong, tell what e.printStackTrace() prints out.

Comment: it didn't print anything. I put a break point on that line and it went over it.

Comment: Then the exception doesn't come from this method, but from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this in eclipse I get java.lang.ClassCastException at this line:

```
return (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
```

the readObject() method is trying to return an Arrays$ArrayList (whatever that is) and your cast is causing it to break. If you change the cast and the return type of your deserialise to be List you'll find it all works.